# Set innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2

Tags: innodb

i use Ubuntu with mysql 5.6
i can't find my.cnf file to add
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2

Can You help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the unix tool:

```
find  /  -name  my.cnf
```